# Android : How to update my text View in a view pager Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I have five image and one text view in a fragment view pager. The view pager contains three same kind of fragment(5 images and one text view).  Initially in the text view of the first fragment has "0". If i select any one of the image on the fragment then  i want increment the text view to "1" and move to the next fragment. While trying to implement that one, the fragment  transition occurs perfectly but the text view is not update to 1. How can i achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `LocalBroadcast`. And you can find other solution in [Android Services](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html). Refer and then if you can't find solution for yourself, comment under my answer